# Sort return by ascending order in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I can't work out where the sort needs to live after using a map function in Meteor. I want to be able to get the returned results and display them in ascending order. The Meteor API docs are a bit light on the sort specifier.

```
Template.foodList.helpers({
  foodCounts: function() {
    return _.map(_.countBy(Foods.find().fetch(), 'text'), function(value, key){
      return {text: key, count: value};
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short but solution using underscore and chaining:

```js
Template.foodList.helpers({
  foodCounts: function() {
    return _.chain(Foods.find().fetch())
      .countBy('text')
      .map(function(v, k) {return {text: k, count: v};})
      .sortBy('count')
      .value();
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the prompt response, that's a really elegant solution. One question though, with that sort going in ascending order on the count, how would I reverse that to be descending etc.

Comment: Edit: Worked it out - just added a negative sign to `.sortBy('-count')`

Comment: Actually it's `.sortBy(function(obj){return -obj.count;})`. Using `-count` just looks for a field called `-count`, which isn't found so it doesn't apply the sort. Alternatively you could get the result of the `_.chain` and then call `.reverse` on it.

Answer (score 1):

as [`_.countBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) manipulates the order of the data, you'd want to sort after that. Probably best to sort after the `_.map` too.

```
Template.foodList.helpers({
  foodCounts: function() {
    var data = _.map(_.countBy(Foods.find().fetch(), 'text'), function(value, key){
          return {text: key, count: value};
    });
    // sort by `text` field
    return _.sortBy(data, function(datum){ 
           return datum.text.toLowerCase(); 
    });
  }
});
```

OR

```
Template.foodList.helpers({
  foodCounts: function() {
    var data = _.map(_.countBy(Foods.find().fetch(), 'text'), function(value, key){
          return {text: key, count: value};
    });
    // sort by count
    return _.sortBy(data, function(datum){ 
           return datum.count; 
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, both answers work in the desired way but I think chaining is a bit more elegant!